# How do I parse street address's so they all uniformly look the same?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Okay so I am writing a C# script which is close to finish, I just need to check to make sure the street names are all the same in regards to abbreviating the end of an address 
Example:

- 1234 Apple **Street**
- 4902 Kennington **Road**
- 4234 house drew **Boulevard**
- ETC....

The highlighted names are the values I want to abbreviate to:

- 1234 Apple **ST**
- 4902 Kennington **RD**
- 4234 house drew **BLVD**

Is there someway method or function in C# that can do this automatically? Or some parsing function that can do this? Please let me know!This also would be helpful if SQL had something like this if it exists

Comment: [`REPLACE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: See also [any of the many address validation API's available](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/address-information-api.htm#_Toc487629494) (US example for USPS customers)

Comment: https://www.google.com/maps/place/Street+Road,+Glastonbury+BA6+9FW/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x48721764c4e400d5:0xab70de048fa7547c?sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwigz8Dfyr_cAhXGDcAKHfElAy8Q8gEwAHoECAIQAQ

Comment: Where are these abbreviated values going to be displayed? Why are you doing this, and why are you not using the actual name? By using abbrvns u r mkng it dffclt++ fr ppl 2 cmprhnd. Like the postal service in whichever countries you are processing addresses for.

Comment: These are going to be displayed within a database through a script. Its parsing the address data from a sql server and then putting the corrected values into ctreeACE server \

Answer (score 1):

Well, you know, that is like a function for making a 3d game, please. And not too complex but with nice assets. If you get out of your little street and travel around al ittle you will find that normalizing addresses EVEN IN ONE COUNTRY is extremely complex.

What you can easily do is not do it - hand it over. Submit your address to an API (Google Geocoding, BIngs etc.) and then take the address parts they return.

Otherwise - last time I did  that it was half a year wit h3 people to get all the freaking special cases out.

Answer (score 0):

As TomTom was saying, this is a much more complex problem than it appears to be, and there are a ridiculous number of edge cases.

I also recommend submitting your addresses to an API for standardization, but just so you know most free ones (like Google) only allow incidental, non-commercial lookups. This means if you have a whole bunch of addresses you need standardized, you would violate their ToS.

[SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com) provides a street address validation and standardization service that you can try out for free. If you are happy with it and need more lookups, you can always buy more. Disclosure: I am a software developer at SmartyStreets.

Answer (score -1):

```
var newString = "1234 Apple Street".Replace("Street", "ST");
```

or also you can use regex pattern to modify your strings

```
var newString= Regex.Replace("1234 Apple Street", "(?i)street", "ST");
```

Comment: He is not asking for replace, he wants to change each and every street name with some abbreviation, and for this there has to be some loop or some array

Answer (score -1):

**"A function that abbreviates street names"**
That sounds a little too specific to be packed with the .NET framework doesn't it?

You can create it, it's simple

Grab the string
Check for any of the options you want (Boulevard,Road, Street) **String.contains** or you can use the **LINQ function** [Enumerable.Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx)
 and treat accordingly

But like @TomTom pointed out you will face Culture problems

Comment: It is simple, until you hit the edge cases.